# Managing R-created files (that are invisible) in Windows File Explorer

Tags: r, rstudio, special-characters, microsoft-file-explorer

I am using an R package which by default saves run-time outputs as CSV with the @ symbol in the filename. These files are **not visible** in File Explorer, but they can be seen with dir() at RStudio's command prompt, and can be opened using RStudio's 'import dataset' menu, which opens a very File-Explorer-like view.

My question is, can I manage these files using File Explorer?

In other words, how do I get the mentioned RStudio's File-Explorer-like view as an actual Windows File Explorer view? Selecting the Hidden Items check box has no effect.

The R package is `kml` running within the `latrend` wrapper package. I don't think there's an option to change the output format, but guidance welcome.

1st EDIT: just a thought - I assume it is the @ symbol that is doing the invisibility trick. Maybe it is something that R or RStudio is doing?

2nd EDIT: My humble apologies! The previous description was not complete (now clarified, hopefully). `latrend` is a wrapper for the culprit package `kml` (among other things).

What follows is the requested example with the relevant output following the `dir()` command. These files are for me not visible in Explorer.

It is also now clear to me that it is *not* the @ that is the cause, as I previously thought! I have changed the title of this question.

```
library(kml)

### generate some dummy data
SOtest <- generateArtificialLongData(25)

### quick result
kml(SOtest,3,10)

## open graphics window for manual selection
x11()
choice(SOtest) ## 'space' to select; 'm' to exit

## to close graphics window
dev.off()

dir() ## show folder contents <snipped>
# [42] ...
# [43] "SOtest-C3-1-Clusters.csv"                                                                    
# [44] "SOtest-C3-1-Details.csv"                                                                     
# [45] "SOtest-C3-1-Traj.bmp"                                                                        
# [46] "SOtest-C3-1-TrajMean.csv"
# [47] ....
```

Comment: I can't see any relevant functions in `latrend` that create csv files. Can you give a reproducible example of how the files get created?

Comment: The situation you’re describing is possible, but implausible. It’s vastly more likely that you are either accidentally looking at the wrong folder in the RStudio file explorer, or that you didn’t refresh the file explorer (there’s a little symbol at the top of the file explorer that looks like a round arrow, a bit like this: ⟳).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup - thanks to Konrad for the idea!

The user guide describes setting a temporary folder, in my case looking something like `C:\Users\<....>\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp<....>` where the files are actually accessible by Explorer.

The clue, though not the relevance/importance, is in the following `kml` user guide code...

```
wd <- getwd()
setwd(tempdir()); getwd()
## ... do stuff ... ##
setwd(wd)
```

Where things are being stored without this step remains a bit of a mystery (to me!), as it looks like the output is in the current `getwd()` context, accessible from within RStudio without a directory change.